# Fixing Server Automatic Shutdown Error – Postgresql 8.4

Tags: postgresql, logging, postgis, postgresql-8.4

The database in use is Postgres database V8.Every one hour there is a server connection   error.The server gets disconnected and needs to be re connected again.
   Please find below the log of the error and let know on a solution to resolve this         error

```
  2012-01-05 13:28:52 CEST LOG: server process (PID 6128) was terminated by exception    0xC0000017
  2012-01-05 13:28:52 CEST HINT: See C include file "ntstatus.h" for a description of the hexadecimal value.
  2012-01-05 13:28:52 CEST LOG: terminating any other active server processes
  2012-01-05 13:28:52 CEST WARNING: terminating connection because of crash of another server process
  2012-01-05 13:28:52 CEST DETAIL:The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll  back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
  2012-01-05 13:28:52 CEST HINT:In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
  2012-01-05 13:28:52 CEST WARNING:terminating connection because of crash of another server process
  2012-01-05 13:28:52 CEST DETAIL:The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Apparently that status is STATUS_NO_MEMORY, so look at your server memory setup (shared_buffers, work_mem et al) and monitor the memory usage on the machine around the time it crashes (if it is regular). Does it always coincide with some sort of scheduled task?

Comment: The server has 24GB RAM and no other applications are installed.The paging size is system managed